# How do you mock $http to give a 404?

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine

How do you mock `$http` so that when you call a specific URL the `.error` function is called?

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/ErrorReturningURL').respond(/* report a 404 */);
}));
```

In my unit test I will be watching for a certain function call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the alternate form of the [`.respond` function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend#methods_when) on the value returned by `when`:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/ErrorReturningURL').respond(404, '');
}));
```

I am using the syntax `function([status,] data[, headers])` for the `respond` function. Hence, I need to explicitly pass in the second argument `data` to ensure that the first argument is interpreted as `status`.